# How to avoid modem initialization with USB gadgetfs CDC driver

Tags: linux-kernel, kernel-module, modem, cdc

I have an embedded device with the USB gadgetfs CDC_ACM driver. Especially, I do:

```
echo "0x0525" > idVendor
echo "0xa4a7" > idProduct
ln -s functions/acm.GS0 configs/c.1
```

The OS running on this embedded device is custom-made and has nothing about modem initialization. The only present executable in the inittab is:

```
::respawn:/sbin/getty -8 115200 ttyGS0 vt100
```

When I link this device to a Linux PC over a USB cable and run minicom, minicom is blocked for 30 seconds with this output:

```
login: ATE1 E0                                                            
Password:                                                                       
ATE1 E0
```

Where does the modem initialization come from and how can I avoid it?

Comment: The problem here is `minicom`. The solution is either not to use it, there are many variants, like `picocom`, or supply a configuration where it is switched off. I personally prefer former.

Comment: No, it's not Minicom. I can reproduce with picocom and I have exchanged on the minicom mailing list